# Image Link with Nofollow tag. Good or Bad practice?

Tags: seo, html

Which is the best practice, from an SEO point of view, if you have a list of products which have both image and text link?

1) one A tag with the image and product name inside?

`<a href="product_link"><img src="..." />
   <span>product name</span></a>`

2) an A tag for each html tag

`<a href="product_link"><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="product_link"><span>product name</span></a>`

It's a good practice to put a rel="nofollow" for the image link like in the image bellow?[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in using nofollow on the image link. Why is the image link any different than the text link? They both point to the same place but only one is an authoritative link and the other is not? This is *not* how nofollow is meant to be used. Unless you do not have editorial control over the content in those links (i.e. you didn't add the links yourself) you should not be using nofollow.

It also does not matter whether you use one or two hyperlinks to get the job done. Use whatever is the easiest to maintain and doesn't have any negative effects on your page's usability.